# Swift: How to wait for an asynchronous, @escaping closure (inline)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, asynchronous, closures

How is it possible to wait for an @escaping closure to complete inline before proceeding?

I am utilizing the write method from AVSpeechSynthesizer, which uses an @escaping closure, so the initial AVAudioBuffer from the callback will return after createSpeechToBuffer has completed.

```
func write(_ utterance: AVSpeechUtterance, toBufferCallback bufferCallback: @escaping AVSpeechSynthesizer.BufferCallback)
```

My method writes speech to a buffer, then resamples and manipulates the output, for a workflow, where speech is done in faster than real-time.

The goal is to perform the task inline, to avoid changing the workflow to standby for the 'didFinish' delegate

```
speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)
```

I **believe** this question can be generalized to dealing with @escaping closures within a function\method

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

let _speechSynth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

func resampleBuffer( inSource: AVAudioPCMBuffer, newSampleRate: Float) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer
{
    // simulate resample data here
    let testCapacity     = 1024
    let audioFormat      = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: Double(newSampleRate), channels: 2)
    let simulateResample = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat!, frameCapacity: UInt32(testCapacity))
    return simulateResample!
}

func createSpeechToBuffer( stringToSpeak: String, sampleRate: Float) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer?
{
    var outBuffer    : AVAudioPCMBuffer? = nil
    let utterance    = AVSpeechUtterance(string: stringToSpeak)
    var speechIsBusy = true
    utterance.voice  = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-us")
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    
    _speechSynth.write(utterance) { (buffer: AVAudioBuffer) in

        guard let pcmBuffer = buffer as? AVAudioPCMBuffer else {
            fatalError("unknown buffer type: \(buffer)")
        }
        
        if ( pcmBuffer.frameLength == 0 ) {
            print("buffer is empty")
        } else {
            print("buffer has content \(buffer)")
        }
        
        outBuffer    = resampleBuffer( inSource: pcmBuffer, newSampleRate: sampleRate)
        speechIsBusy = false
//        semaphore.signal()
    }
    
    // wait for completion of func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)
    
//        while ( _speechSynth.isSpeaking )
//        {
//            /* arbitrary task waiting for write to complete */
//        }
//
//        while ( speechIsBusy )
//        {
//            /* arbitrary task waiting for write to complete */
//        }
//    semaphore.wait()
    return outBuffer
}

print("SUCCESS is waiting, returning the non-nil output from the resampleBuffer method.")

for indx in 1...10
{
    let sentence  = "This is sentence number \(indx). [[slnc 3000]] \n"
    let outBuffer = createSpeechToBuffer( stringToSpeak: sentence, sampleRate: 48000.0)
    print("outBuffer: \(String(describing: outBuffer))")
}
```

After I wrote the createSpeechToBuffer method and it failed to produce the desired output (inline), I realized that it returns before getting the results of the resampling. The callback is escaping, so the initial AVAudioBuffer from the callback will return after createSpeechToBuffer has completed. The actual resampling does work, however I currently must save the result and continue after being notified by the delegate "didFinish utterance" to proceed.

Attempts at waiting for _speechSynth.isSpeaking, speechIsBusy flag, dispatch queue and semaphore are blocking the write method (using _speechSynth.write) from completing.

How is it possible to wait for the result inline versus recreating a workflow depending on the delegate "didFinish utterance"?

I'm on macOS 11.4 (Big Sur) but I believe this question is applicable to macOS and ios

Comment: Are you using Swift 5.5?

Comment: You want to turn an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.  Blocking on a semaphore as you have in your commented code is one such approach, but you do need to be careful to avoid deadlocks and ensure that you don't block the main queue (which it looks like you are doing). You could dispatch the tasks onto another serial dispatch queue and use a `DispatchGroup` `notify` to identify when all work is done, or better, just embrace the asynchronous function and pass a closure to `createSpeechToBuffer`, again using a `DispatchGroup` to indentify when all work is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the commented-out code for `DispatchSemaphore` would work if the `@escaping` closure is run concurrently, and I think the problem is that it is run *serially*, or more accurately, not run at all, because it is scheduled to run serially.  I'm not specifically familiar with the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` API, but from your description, it sounds to me as though it's calling on the main dispatch queue, which is a *serial* queue. You call wait to block until `_speechSynth.write` completes, but that's blocking the main thread, which prevents it from ever continuing to the next iteration of the run loop, so the actual work of `_speechSynth.write` never even starts.

Let's back up.  Somewhere behind the scenes your closure is almost certainly called via `DispatchQueue.main`'s `async` method, either because that's where `speechSynth.write` does its work then calls your closure synchronously on the current thread at the time, or because it explicitly calls it on the main thread.

A lot of programmers are sometimes confused as to exactly what `async` does.  All `async` means is "schedule this task and return control to the caller immediately".  That's it. It does *not* mean that the task will be run concurrently, only that it will be run later.  Whether it is run concurrently or serially is an attribute of the `DispatchQueue` whose `async` method is being called.  Concurrent queues spin up threads for their tasks, which either can be run in parallel on different CPU cores (true concurrency), or interleaved with the current thread on the same core (preemptive multitasking).  Serial queues on the other hand have a run loop as in `NSRunLoop`, and run their scheduled tasks *synchronously* after dequeuing them.

To illustrate what I mean, the main run loop looks vaguely like this, and other run loops are similar:

```swift
while !quit
{
    if an event is waiting {
        dispatch the event <-- Your code is likely blocking in here
    }
    else if a task is waiting in the queue 
    {
        dequeue the task
        execute the task <-- Your closure would be run here
    }
    else if a timer has expired {
       run timer task
    }
    else if some view needs updating {
        call the view's draw(rect:) method
    }
    else { probably other things I'm forgetting }
}
```

`createSpeechToBuffer` is almost certainly being run in response to some event processing, which means that when it blocks, it does not return back to the run loop to continue to the next iteration where it checks for tasks in the queue... which from the behavior you describe, seems to include the work being done by `_speechSynth.write`... the very thing you're waiting for.

You can try explicitly creating a `.concurrent` `DispatchQueue` and using it to wrap the call to `_speechSynth.write` in an explicit `async` call, but that *probably* won't work, and even if it does, it will be fragile to changes Apple might make to `AVSpeechSynthesizer`'s implementation.

The safe way is to not block... but that means re-thinking your work flow a little.  Basically whatever code would be called after `createSpeechToBuffer` returns should be called at the end of your closure.  Of course, as currently written `createSpeechToBuffer` doesn't know what that code is (nor should it).  The solution is to inject it as a parameter... meaning `createSpeechToBuffer` itself would also take an `@escaping` closure.  And of course, that means it can't return the buffer, but instead passes it to the closure.

```swift
func createSpeechToBuffer(
    stringToSpeak: String,
    sampleRate: Float,
    onCompletion: @escaping (AVAudioPCMBuffer?) -> Void) 
{
    let utterance    = AVSpeechUtterance(string: stringToSpeak)
    utterance.voice  = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-us")
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    
    _speechSynth.write(utterance) { (buffer: AVAudioBuffer) in

        guard let pcmBuffer = buffer as? AVAudioPCMBuffer else {
            fatalError("unknown buffer type: \(buffer)")
        }
        
        if ( pcmBuffer.frameLength == 0 ) {
            print("buffer is empty")
        } else {
            print("buffer has content \(buffer)")
        }
        
        onCompletion(
            resampleBuffer(
                inSource: pcmBuffer, 
                newSampleRate: sampleRate
            )
        )
    }
}
```

If you *really* want to maintain the existing API, the other approach is to move the entire workflow itself to a `.concurrent` `DispatchQueue`, which you can block to your heart's content without worry that it will block the main thread. `AVSpeechSynthesizer` could schedule its work wherever it likes without a problem.

If using Swift 5.5 is an option, you might look into its `async` and `await` keywords.   The compiler enforces a proper `async` context for them so that you don't block the main thread.

### Update to answer how to call my version.

Let's say your code that calls `createSpeechToBuffer` currently looks like this:

```swift
guard let buffer = createSpeechToBuffer(stringToSpeak: "Hello", sampleRate: sampleRate)
else { fatalError("Could not create speechBuffer") }

doSomethingWithSpeechBuffer(buffer)
```

You'd call the new version like this:

```swift
createSpeechToBuffer(stringToSpeak: "Hello", sampleRate: sampleRate) 
{
    guard let buffer = $0 else {
        fatalError("Could not create speechBuffer")
    }

    doSomethingWithSpeechBuffer(buffer)
}
```

Comment: This is OUTSTANDING. 
There is one that I would add, which is how to call your improved method.

Comment: I'm glad it's helpful.  You call pretty much exactly like you did, except instead of just printing, you actually do something do whatever you were planning to do with the buffer.  I'll update my answer to show a code example.

Comment: Incidentally, I have an `Async` Swift package you might find useful (https://github.com/chipjarred/Async).  It provides a `Future` type and corresponding `Promise`.  The key aspect that you might find useful is that `Future` is implemented so that it can be used as a stand-in for a value that will be set when some async closure completes - ie, you can return it, pass it around, store it away, etc...  You still have to worry about blocking the main thread when want to get the actual value, but it might be of some help in preserving something like your existing workflow.